# Why does git mergetool show no conflicts, even though there are conflict markers present in files after a merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-config, mergetool, p4merge

I’m checked out on `feature/my-branch` and running `git merge dev`. The conflict markers added to the file are:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    let foo = "foo"
    let bar = "bar"
||||||| merged common ancestors
    let baz = "baz"
    let bar = "bar"
=======
    let baz = "baz"
    let qux = "qux"
>>>>>>> dev
```

I then run `git mergetool`. I have `p4mergetool` set as my mergetool and it seems to be working. My `.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
    tool = p4mergetool
    conflictstyle = diff3
[mergetool "p4mergetool"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/Resources/launchp4merge $PWD/$BASE $PWD/$REMOTE $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$MERGED
    trustExitCode = true
```

The `git mergetool` auto resolves the above conflict (0 conflicts shown in the tool) as:

```
let foo = "foo"
let qux = "qux"
```

This sort of makes sense: even though HEAD and dev are in conflict, we can see that one branch updated one line and the other branch updated the other line. So we can *probably* assume what we want.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to run/configure `git-mergetool` or `p4mergetool` specifically to NOT make this assumption and still show a conflict?
2. Do I need to run both commands:

   ```
   git merge dev
   git mergetool
   ```

   to have this conflict solved this automatically? I.e. produce the output:

   ```
   let foo = "foo"
   let qux = "qux"
   ```

Said another way: is there a git merge strategy/arguments that I can use to simply run the `merge` command to produce:

```
let foo = "foo"
let qux = "qux"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This sort of makes sense: even though HEAD and dev are in conflict, we can see that one branch updated one line and the other branch updated the other line. So we can *probably* assume what we want.

That's exactly right.

> 1. Is there a way to run/configure `git-mergetool` or `p4mergetool` specifically to NOT make this assumption and still show a conflict?

`git mergetool` does not make the assumption, so we can conclude that `p4mergetool` must be the one doing it.  I don't have `p4mergetool`, though, so I don't know if it has a configuration knob to change this.

> 2. Do I need to run both commands ...

Yes: Git's own merge is kind of dumb and merely notices that, gosh, this range of changes on the left abuts (touches) or overlaps this other range of changes on the right, so let's call it a conflict and make the user handle it.  In this case, the left-side change (from baz to foo) came just before the right-side change (bar to qux), so the two ranges touched at the edges and Git itself declared a conflict.  Had there been one line in between, `git merge` would have combined the changes on its own, without calling it a conflict.

(Note that using `-X ours` or `-X theirs` would resolve the conflict by discarding one side's change and using only the other's.  Again you'd never even get to the point of having `p4mergetool` do its own thing.)

What `git mergetool` does is extract the three files—merge base, left or local or `--ours`, and right or remote or `--theirs` versions of some file—and run some other, non-Git program on the three files.  When that program finishes, `git mergetool` can either trust its exit code to decide whether the tool itself merged the files correctly, or run some file comparisons, or just ask you directly: is the work-tree copy of the file now the correct merged copy?

If the work-tree copy is now the correct final result (or at least `git mergetool` believes this), `git mergetool` runs `git add`, which marks the conflict as being resolved.<sup>1</sup>  Otherwise, it leaves the conflict in place.

(I tend to just resolve merge conflicts in my editor.)

---

<sup>1</sup>A file is *unmerged* if there are any copies of it in any nonzero index slots.  A file is *merged* if there is one copy of it, in slot zero—the normal slot number.  Except using some of Git's low-level diagnostic-ish commands (`git ls-index --stage`, really), you can't actually *see* these staging slot numbers, but `git status` calls the file *unmerged* and tells you whether it is in all three slots (`UU`) or in just the left or right one (`UD` and `DU` respectively).  I'm not sure off hand what `git status` says about a file in slot 1, which would represent the merge base copy of a file with a rename/rename conflict.

Normally we just use `git add` or perhaps `git rm` to overwrite the higher-numbered slots.  In the rare case of wanting to restore a resolved file to conflicted state, `git checkout -m` can do that.

Comment: Thanks @torek! About to accept the answer. Just curious:

"I don't have p4mergetool, though, so I don't know if it has a configuration knob to change this."

Do you know of _any_ mergetools that have a configuration for this?

Comment: No - I don't use any of them. I have fired up vimdiff as a merge tool once or twice just to see how it looks, and I've seen one non-Git merge tool in action once. I've run `git mergetool` and pointed it at a few things, but never experimented with kdiff3 or whatever the KDE merge tool thing is...